# how to provide a necessary information for overloaded Operator>>

Tags: c++

## Objective:

Reading input on their respective classes to keep the concern separated. Example Scenario:

- `Graph` know how to read the input data of a graph data format.
- `Edge` know how to read input data of an edge data format.
- `Vertex` know how to read the input of vertex data format.

### Input Format:

```
4
3
0 1
1 2
3 2
```

1. First Line is # of `V` vertices
2. Second Line is # of `E` edges
3. The next `E` lines are the edges data with two integer `u` and `v` are the index it connects.

### Crafted Sample Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct Vertex {
    int index;
};

struct Edge {
    Vertex* adjacencies[2]; // 2 end point.

    Edge(Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2){
        adjacencies[0] = v1;
        adjacencies[1] = v2;
    }

    Edge(){ }

    friend std::istream&
    operator>>(std::istream &in, Edge &edge) {
        int v1, v2;
        in >> v1 >> v2;

        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // From these integers v1 & v2, we need the vertex pointer.
        // The vertex pointer is retrievable from the graph object.
        // However graph is not available in this friend function.
        // graph object somehow available on the caller. But how??
        // -------------------------------------------------------

        Vertex* v1_ptr = nullptr; // ????
        Vertex* v2_ptr = nullptr; // ????

        edge = Edge(v1_ptr, v2_ptr);

        return in;
    }
};

struct Graph {
    Vertex vertices[10];
    Edge edges[10];

    friend std::istream&
    operator>>(std::istream &in, Graph &graph) {
        int e;
        in >> e; // Number of Edges
        for (int i = 0; i < e; ++i){
            in >> graph.edges[i];
        }
        return in;
    }
};

int main(){
    Graph graph;
    cin >> graph;
    return 0;
}
```

### Question:

Notice how I read all of those input format by using `cin >> graph`. And inside `Graph::operator>>` I want to further nested the overload of input redirection when reading the `Edge` data. But `Edge::operator>>` data requires `Vertex` information which is available on the `Graph` (its caller).

- Am I doing fine so far? regarding the separation of its input reading on different classes
- How can we inform the `Graph.vertices` into the `Edge::operator>>` when calling it?
- How can I achieve the same objective if that method is not possible?

Comment: For simplicity, I didn't read the vertex input data, but it is straightforward, since there is no back dependencies like the edge has

Comment: You cannot provide _extra arguments_ for operator functions, they have a fixed number of parameters. If you need more state info, wrap the `std::istream` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie to keep thing simple actually. Although I believe the cleaner solution is to create a Reader class itself, I guess? But for simplicity, I'm just wanted to simulate a similar problem

Comment: `edge = Edge(v1_ptr, v2_ptr);` -- Unless those pointers point to a dynamically allocated `int`, you're storing pointers to local variables, which will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I would make regular named functions, or put everything in the `Graph` overload. (It's not like these are going to get used outside of that overload, anyway.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm still new to this, and i don't understand what you mean about why storing pointer to local variable will lead to undefined behavior. `v1_ptr` & `v2_ptr` is determined by the v1_ptr should be one of the address of the array element.

Comment: @Yeo What is the purpose of `v1` and `v2` in your function?  If your goal was to store pointers to those values, and then initialize `Edge` with those values, that's not going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `v1` & `v2` is just temporary to receive the input data, I was not sure if that was necessary in the first place. But `v1` & `v2` will be used to retrieved the address in the main graph vertices, (something like `v1_ptr = &graph->vertices[v1]`)

Answer (score 0):

> - Am I doing fine so far? regarding the separation of its input reading on different classes

The design seems ok for me.

> - How can we inform the Graph.vertices into the Edge::operator>> when calling it?

It is not possible without extra arguments.

> - How can I achieve the same objective if that method is not possible?

You should replace Edge::operator>> by a method with another argument `read(std::istream&, EdgeReadParameters& params)` that contains a map from int to a `Vertex*` located in the `Graph` and a reference to the `Graph::vertices`. This map can be build incrementally and possibly by the `read` method if no `Vertex` is in connection with a `int` read - the reference to `Graph::vertices` will own the newly created `Vertex`. The `EdgeReadParameters` object should be local to the `Graph::operator>>` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up additional information using the `iword()` or `pword()` members of `std::ios_base` (a common base class of both `std::istream` and `std::ostream`): given an index these provide access to `int&` (for `iword()`) and `void*&` (for `pword()`). A use of these functions could look something like this:

```
constexpr int graph_index = std::ios_base::xalloc(); // there is no "xdealloc()"
enter code here
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Graph& graph) {
    in.pword(graph_index) = &graph;
    // ...
    Edge e;
    in >> e;
    // ...
 }

 std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Edge& edge) {
     Graph* g = static_cast<Graph*>(in.pword(graph_index);
     // use g to obtain the relevant context and the edges
 }
```